# Macbook Air 2014 Yosemite "soft freeze"

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

I have a 2014 Macbook Air running Yosemite 10.10.2 that is "soft freezing" regularly. By that I mean that the (built-in) keyboard and trackpad do not respond at all anymore, but I can see that if there were any animated webpages running at the time of the freeze, the animation continues to run, meaning that at the very least the GPU and Safari seem to be still running.

Note: I've had a Bluetooth mouse connected (which also remains completely unresponsive after the freeze) the last times it has frozen, I can't recall whether that was always the case.

These are the last lines of my system logs the last time it froze:

```
29/3/15 19:59:00,731 CoreServicesUIAgent[223]: unexpected message <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff7cee9c60> { count = 1, contents =
        "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff7cee9f70> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}>
29/3/15 19:59:15,971 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
29/3/15 19:59:34,000 kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][ProcessEventDataWL] -- Destroying device even though we had an error on disconnection -- calling DestroyDeviceWithDisconnectionResults()
29/3/15 19:59:34,500 loginwindow[67]: Preferred Localizations total: 1 contents (
    es
)
29/3/15 20:01:25,000 bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1427652085 0
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: It looks like it looses the connection to the BT mouse and does not fall back to enable the Track pad. Check your BT mouse battery.

Comment: The Bluetooth mouse battery shows at over 50%, and would that explain the (built-in) keyboard not working at all?

Comment: As far as I know the built-in Bluetooth adapter is also connected to USB internally.  Do you have other USB devices connected to your computer?  Especially high-powered ones like like iPhone or iPad or a USB-powered hard drive when this is happening?  If so, you may experience that the entire USB system gets reset and will not work until its drivers are reloaded/restarted.

Comment: No, nothing on the USB ports at all. The laptop was running on battery power, with nothing connected to it except wirelessly: the Wi-Fi adapter connected to the AirPort Extreme, the Bluetooth Adapter connected to an HP Bluetooth mouse.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have exactly the same problem with osx 10.10.5 and HP Bluetooth mouse

Comment: Nope, I was unable to find a solution. Instead I switched to a Logitech M557 and have had no trouble whatsoever since